# What do the equations on this gate mean or relate to?

Tags: mathematical-physics

These equations are on gates to the John Dalton building in Manchester UK:
$$X \geq Y \text{ iff } \not\exists \, x_r \leq Y \text{ & } X \leq Y_L $$
$$X = Y \text{ iff } X \leq Y \text{ & } Y \geq X$$
Here’s a picture of the gates

[image: Gates at the John Dalton building]

Does anybody know what they mean or which work they relate to? I've tagged this mathematical physics, but am not really sure if this is correct.

Comment: Surely the second one is an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Conway's surreal numbers -- check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_numbers and his ONAG, and Knuth's introductory book for more information.